# Why does subclassing the main ViewController's view causes delegates to never fire?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, delegates

I made a **customView** that implements its own **delegate** and set it up inside the main  **viewController**. It works perfectly well, it's the standard practice, there's no need to show any code.

For the sake of better organizing the code I created a manager called **customManager** that contains the **customView** and the main viewController's **view**.

Instead of having all the code that it's needed inside the viewController (managing how the customView is setup and also listening to its delegate) I moved all that code to the customManager instead. That's why I made the customManager just to clear up the code that's inside the viewController.

All renders properly but the delegate never fires.

**CustomManager.h**

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@interface CustomManager : NSObject <CustomViewDelegate>

@property (weak) UIView *view; // viewController's view

@property (strong) CustomView *customView;

- (void)load;

@end
```

**CustomManager.m**

```
#import "CustomManager.h"

@implementation CustomManager

// Initialization Method

- (void)load {

    _customView = [[CustomView alloc] init];

    _customView.delegate = self; // !!!

    _customView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, _view.frame.size.width, _view.frame.size.height - 20.0);

    [_view addSubview:_customView];
}

#pragma mark - CustomViewDelegate

// Delegate Methods

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import "CustomManager.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong) CustomManager *customManager;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _customManager = [[CustomManager alloc] init];

    _customManager.view = self.view;

    [_customManager load];

    // 1. The load method above removes the code needed here for initializing the customView and setting it up correctly.
    // 2. The delegate methods are now in the customManager and leave the space below clear.
}

@end
```

Comment: Like asked in the previous thread (that was almost the same question): can we se how you call the delegate? Then the delegate protocol? BTW. You should usually pass weak references of self to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: What are weak references to self? The delegate is called from UIGestureRecognizers that are added to subviews inside the CustomView.

Comment: First: Check in your custom view If delegate is set or log its value to check if its set. Second: passing self will create a strong reference pointer. Then both objects can never deallocate. If one is a weak reference though they can.

Comment: This is why I set UIView *view to be weak. For some reason it works now but this wasn't what I was originally going for. Instead I tried to have a weak reference to the viewController itself and not just the view.

Comment: Even the reference to the viewController works now. Analysis paralysis.

Comment: This is rather an Antipattern. You should not have your delegate own view. Your controller should own both view and delegate and delegate can then keep week reference of your view or viewcontroller.

Comment: I don't understand this. For example, the UITableView owns the UITableViewDelegate, correct?